# Save to Rails database html within elements

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save the HTML within an element when I load the view. I found [this documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/HTML/Selector.html) but I am new to RoR and I get the following error:

> uninitialized constant HomeController::HTML

Here is my html

```
<div class="container_content">
  <h2>The element I want to save in my db</h2>
  <p>And this one too!</p>
</div>
```

The controller rendering the view with the html

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    selector = HTML::Selector.new "div.container_content"
    Content.create html: selector, team_id: 1, last_update: Time.now
  end
end
```

Maybe I should try to select the html with javascript and find a way to send it to the database? I don't want to refresh the page in order to save the html.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you explain in a broader sense what you're trying to do?  Why do you want to store the html in the database?

Comment: I want to create a new page for the user with a html template. Then they are able to modify the content. In order to achieve that, I want to save a new page with the template html first. Then update the content when the user change it. Let me know if it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the html content in a partial then use [ApplicationController.render](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html) or [render_to_string](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html)

i.e. Something like

```
content = HomeController.render('path/to/partial')
```

or

```
content = render_to_string(partial: 'path/to/partial')
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I could save the edited content then? The idea is to add a contenteditable="true" to the elements so that the user can change it.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean, I thought you just wanted to set up a default

Comment: Maybe I can use your solution for the creation of the content for the new user and then use some javascript to update the displayed content